# Passing a Cookie Value Through Form To PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cookies, input

I made this post to try to see if there is a different way (or something I'm doing wrong) to get my **Cookie with an value** into a **hidden input** which can send the value **through a form** to my **MySQL database**.

I am trying to grab a cookie with my "getCookie()" function and then put it in a hidden form to then pass through to my database. There may be simpler ways I am unaware of, but currently this is what I have:

Inside my form I have:

`var cookie_val = getCookie("id");` and
`$('input[name=id]').val(cookie_val);`

When outputting the "getCookie("user")"  simply with a document write I get the value that I am looking for, however, in my MySQL database when it arrives it ends up as a value of 0. I am not fully understanding of how 
`$('input[name=id]').val(cookie_val);`
works.

I am fairly confident that my PHP code is not the issue in all of this.

Comment: Open your browser developer tools. When you hit submit, you should be able to see the actual form information that is sent to the server. This will tell you if the problem is on client or server-side.

Comment: aren't cookies sent as part of the request headers?

Comment: if you already have the value stored inside a cookie, why you need to put the value in the form and resubmit it ? isn't it already available in the next form submission ?

Comment: That's why i'm looking for a better way to do it, because this is new territory for me, not something that I know how to do.

Comment: On the PHP side there's a global variable called [`$_COOKIE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) that should give you all the information you are looking for. It is keyed by cookie name, too, unlike JS, so it is a little friendlier